# Elastic Search Invalid Pattern Given

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, apache-spark

I have this code below:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark-Hbase").setMaster("local[2]")
      .set("es.index.auto.create", "true")
      .set("es.resource", "test")
      .set("es.nodes", "127.0.0.1")
      .set("es.output.json", "true")

/* More code */

DStream.map {
      _._2
}.foreachRDD { (rdd: RDD[String]) =>
    EsSpark.saveJsonToEs(rdd, "127.0.0.1")
}
```

I keep getting an error for the `elastic search` es.nodes property saying:

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: invalid pattern given 127.0.0.1/
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:50)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.field.AbstractIndexExtractor.compile(AbstractIndexExtractor.java:51)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestService.createWriter(RestService.java:398)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsRDDWriter.write(EsRDDWriter.scala:40)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$$anonfun$saveToEs$1.apply(EsSpark.scala:67)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$$anonfun$saveToEs$1.apply(EsSpark.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    ... 3 more
```

Am I doing something wrong by putting `127.0.0.1`? I tried putting the port as by doing `127.0.0.1:9200` but it still didn't work. Does anyone have any pointers? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind I figured it out. This method `saveJsonToEs`:

```
EsSpark.saveJsonToEs(rdd, "127.0.0.1")
```

Doesn't take the IP address of the elastic search cluster but rather the index in Elastic search to save the `String` rdd to.

So it should be something like this:

```
EsSpark.saveJsonToEs(rdd, "test/sampleApp") /* Where `test` is the `index` and `sampleApp` is the `type` */
```

The second parameter has to be in the type `Requires the format <index>/<type>`. Index and type could be anything that makes sense for your certain application. Note the index doesn't have to be present in elastic search previously. You can use the property on your `Spark Conf` object: `set("es.index.auto.create", "true")` to auto create it. As shown in my properties above.

For reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html

In the link above Command+f and search for `Writing existing JSON to Elasticsearch`.